# Evaluate limit $\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \frac {\ln(\tan 2x )}{\ln(\tan 3x )} $

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I'm supposed to evaluate this limit using L'Hopital's rule.

> $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\ln(\tan 2x )}{\ln(\tan 3x )} $$

I find the indeterminate form of $\frac{0}{0}$. The latter tells me that L'Hopital's is an option, after applying the rule once I end up with:

> $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\frac {1}{\tan 2x}*\sec^2(2x)*2}{\frac {1}{\tan 3x}*\sec^2(3x)*3} $$

After this step however I seem to get lost in my own translation time and time again. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Recall $(\tan u)/u \to 0.$

Comment: Actually, $\ln(u)\to-\infty$ as $u\to0$.

Comment: @zhw. applying this rule gives me $\frac{2}{3}$ as a solution while I know that the solution has to be 1..

Comment: @SimpleArt LHR applies when the denominator goes to $\pm \infty$.

Comment: @TheAlPaca02 $(2/3)(3/2)=1$

Comment: @Dr.MV Was actually pointing out that the OP thinks it is in the form of $\frac00$

Comment: @SimpleArt sorry my mistake, it is $\frac{\inf}{\inf}$ right? This doesn't change anything i believe

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't, but the mistaking of $\ln(0)\to-\infty$ tends to catch people, and sometimes you end up applying L'Hospital's incorrectly, like in $\frac{\ln(x)}x$

Comment: Can you exponentiate the expression?

Comment: @SimpleArt thanks for the concern but its a simple mistake on my part. Copied the code from a different post for faster formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that

$$\frac{\tan(3x)}{\tan(2x)}=\left(\frac{\sin(3x)}{3x}\right)\left(\frac{3x}{2x}\right)\left(\frac{2x}{\sin(2x)}\right)\left(\frac{\sec(3x)}{\sec(2x)}\right)$$

Comment: In this case with the limit going to 0 all terms are equal to 1 except $\frac{3x}{2x}$ correct?

Comment: @TheAlPaca02 Note that $\frac xx=1$

Comment: @SimpleArt Ah yes ofcourse. By splitting up $\frac{3x}{2x}$ into $\frac{3}{2} * \frac{x}{x}$ and combining this with $\frac{2}{3}$ the total $=1$

Comment: @Dr. MV I am able to derive all the terms in your given equality using $tanx = \frac{sinx}{cosx}$ and $secx = \frac{1}{cosx}$. But where does the term $\frac{3x}{2x}$ come from exactly?

Comment: @TheAlPaca02 Note that we multiplied by $1=\frac{2x}{3x}\frac{3x}{2x}$ and grouped one of these fractions with $\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(2x)}$.